# Pgfplots renders the graph at half the page

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to draw three graphs one under the other in the same tikzpicture. PGFPlots is rendering a graph this way:

[image]

Minimal working example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend pos=north east,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={->},
width=\textwidth,
height=6cm,
xmin=0,
xmax=100000,
x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
xlabel={Number of Messages Received at the Consumer},
ylabel={Worker Number},
name=plot1
]
\addplot+[const plot, mark=none] coordinates{ 

};
\legend{Optimal:Peer 1}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
legend pos=north east,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={->},
width=\textwidth,
height=6cm,
xmin=0,
xmax=100000,
x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
xlabel={Number of Messages Received at the Consumer},
ylabel={Worker Number},
at=(plot1.below south west), anchor=north west,
name=plot2
]

\addplot+[const plot, mark=none] coordinates{

};


\addplot+[const plot, mark=none] coordinates{

};
\legend{Battery:Peer 1, Battery:Peer 2, }
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
legend pos=north east,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={->},
width=\textwidth,
height=6cm,
xmin=0,
xmax=100000,
x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
xlabel={Number of Messages Received at the Consumer},
ylabel={Worker Number},
at=(plot2.below south west), anchor=north east,
name=plot3
]

\addplot+[const plot, mark=none] coordinates{

};


\addplot+[const plot, mark=none] coordinates{

};
\legend{Leaving:Peer1, Leaving:Peer2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Problem may be related to the `at` keyword, but I have been using the *same* exact piece of code to draw the graph this way on another file and it shows the graphs correctly one under the other...

Comment: I doubt that you use the *exact same* piece of code ... Please change `anchor=north east` to `anchor=north west` for the last `axis` environment and you will have the desired result ...

Comment: Copy-pasted from the other file. Not sure what is happening there then. Your solution worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: *g. Shall we close this question as being solved in the comments, shall I write an answer or do you simply want to delete the question?

Comment: Maybe this turns out to be useful for somebody in the future. Just write it as a solution and I give you the green checkmark ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already stated in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358600/pgfplots-renders-the-graph-at-half-the-page#comment883313_358600) you should replace `anchor=north east` to `anchor=north west` for the last `axis` environment and you will have the desired result.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % moved `axis' options that are in common to this style and used it later
        my axis style/.style={
            legend pos=north east,
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={->},
            width=\textwidth,
            height=6cm,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=100000,
            x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
            y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
            xlabel={Number of Messages Received at the Consumer},
            ylabel={Worker Number},
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        my axis style,
        name=plot1,
    ]
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        my axis style,
        at=(plot1.below south west),
        anchor=north west,
        name=plot2,
    ]
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        my axis style,
        at=(plot2.below south west),
%        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%        anchor=north east,      % <-- that is the line that is wrong
        anchor=north west,      % <-- this is how it should look like
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        name=plot3,
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]